# What is the proper way to pass mass action selected IDs to a UI Component form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponents

I am working on a section , where the admin can select multiple customers from customer grid, and then select an custom option from massAction drop down.

[image]

Which will open an ui form.

[image]

On clicking on send, I want to send message to the selected customers.

I am currently setting the selected customer ids in session at the mass action controller, and getting them in the form submit controller.
But is there any proper way to do this ? Without using session ?

Following is what I have tried

`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`

```xml
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="sms_notification">
            <settings>
                <url path="daplcore/notification/view"/>
                <type>sms_notification</type>
                <label translate="true">Send Notification/Sms</label>
            </settings>
        </action>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
```

`Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Notification/View.php`
`

```php
public function execute()
{
    $selectedIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');
    $this->adminSession->setSelectedCustomers($selectedIds);

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Notification Sender')));

    return $resultPage;
}
```

`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/daplcore_notification_view.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="daplcore_notification_view_ui"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/daplcore_notification_view_ui.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">daplcore_notification_view_ui.daplcore_notification_view_ui_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Notification Form</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Notification\Send"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>daplcore_notification_view_ui</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>daplcore_notification_view_ui.daplcore_notification_view_ui_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="daplcore_notification_view_ui_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="daplcore/notification/send"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\Module\Model\Ui\NotificationDataProvider" name="daplcore_notification_view_ui_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="type" sortOrder="10" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Notification Type</label>
                <dataScope>type</dataScope>
                <switcherConfig>
                    <rules>
                        <rule name="0">
                            <value>sms</value>
                            <actions>
                                <action name="0">
                                    <target>daplcore_notification_view_ui.daplcore_notification_view_ui.general.title</target>
                                    <callback>hide</callback>
                                </action>
                            </actions>
                        </rule>
                        <rule name="1">
                            <value>push</value>
                            <actions>
                                <action name="0">
                                    <target>daplcore_notification_view_ui.daplcore_notification_view_ui.general.title</target>
                                    <callback>show</callback>
                                </action>
                            </actions>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </switcherConfig>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Source\NotificationOptions" />
                        <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="title" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
                <dataScope>title</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="body" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>textarea</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Body</label>
                <dataScope>body</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: @MahdiAlikhani No. Had to use session to store the selected items.

Comment: weird. For me, I have an issue if I select more than a specific number to store in the session